# Matlab, plotting classes of points in specific areas in axis

Tags: matlab

Hi and thanks for any help in advance, i am in the process of plotting a series of classified points in an axis. What i am trying to achieve is to have the plotted classes, which are in different colors dependant upon their class, is to have each of the classes plotted in each corner of the axis area.

---

This is my plot command

```
DATA = [X labels];
Z = (DATA(:,3)); % select all row three as classes
plot (DATA (Z == 1, 1), DATA (Z == 1, 2), 'k.', 'markersize', 5)
hold on
grid on
plot (DATA (Z == 2, 1), DATA (Z == 2, 2), 'rx', 'markersize', 5)
plot (DATA (Z == 3, 1), DATA (Z == 3, 2), 'g^', 'markersize', 5)
plot (DATA (Z == 4, 1), DATA (Z == 4, 2), 'b.', 'markersize', 5)
```

I need to plot each class in each corner of the axis

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Are you looking for the `legend` command?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you're asking for. Do you want to plot the data so that `[0,0]` is, say, on the bottom left for `Z==1`, on the bottom right for `Z==2`, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to plot?

> DATA = [rand(10,2),round(rand(10,1)*4)];% sample data
>
> Z = DATA(:,3);
>
> figure; hold on; axis tight; axis equal; grid on; box on;
>
> p1=plot (DATA (Z == 1, 1), DATA (Z == 1, 2), 'k.', 'markersize', 5);
>
> p2=plot (DATA (Z == 2, 1), DATA (Z == 2, 2), 'rx', 'markersize', 5);
>
> p3=plot (DATA (Z == 3, 1), DATA (Z == 3, 2), 'g^', 'markersize', 5);
>
> p4=plot (DATA (Z == 4, 1), DATA (Z == 4, 2), 'b.', 'markersize', 5);
>
> legend([p1,p2,p3,p4],'Apple','Carrot','Orange','Banana')

Comment: Thanks for the proposed suggestions but i now have it sorted For any1 thats interest d1 = rand(250,2)* 0.3 + 0.7;
m1 = [d1(1:250,:),repmat(2, 250, 1);]; % Add class labels
data1 = m1(:, 1:2); % Split into points and labels
labels1 = m1(:, 3);
% plot data as per coordinates and colors for classes
plot (m1 (labels1 == 2, 1), m1 (labels1 == 2, 2), 'gx', 'markersize', 5)